# UIImageView is not always shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I'm debugging a problem with an imageView not being shown.

```
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
NSLog(@"imageView right after initialization is: %@", imageView);

imageView.frame = CGRectMake(2, 0, 316, 45);
imageView.layer.zPosition = zPos;
NSLog(@"imageView after running the setters: %@", imageView);

[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

The weird part is that sometimes the `imageView` gets displayed, sometimes it's not (about 75% of the time it's displayed).

`imageView` is not accessed anywhere except the code above.

What I noticed is that when the `imageView` **is not displayed**, the first log statement shows that:

> imageView right after initialization is: <UIImageView: 0x9eaa760;
>   frame = (0 0; 0 0); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer:
>   0x9ec04a0>>

When the image view **is displayed**:

> imageView right after initialization is: <UIImageView: 0xaa61ad0;
>   frame = (0 0; 644 88); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer
>   = <CALayer: 0xaa61330&rt;&rt;

EDITED:
I ran tens of tests, the imageView always behaves the same: when it is not shown, the initial frame is (0 0; 0 0). When it's not, it's always some other value.

P.S. I'm not using ARC.

Comment: You set frame using CGRectMake(2, 0, 316, 45) in your code, why in logs it shows frame = (0 0; 644 88)?

Comment: What method is the above code in? Is it in viewDidLoad? This smells like an auto-layout issue ...

Comment: have you tried running the same code with a different image name? do you get the exact same results? have you tested with loading huge images, very small images? tests like these can help isolate the problem at least..

Comment: @Veelian, it shows frame = (0 0; 644 88) in the first log statement, when the frame is not yet set.

Comment: @DavidDoyle, yes, it's in the viewDidLoad!

Comment: `I ran tens of tests, the connection is always there.` what does connection in this line refer to? This the connection is for imageView , then why do you have to initialize it again and set the frame?

Comment: @abbood, tested the code with different images (same sizes though): nothing changed

Comment: @PratyushaTerli, I changed this line in the question, hope it's clear this time what I meant.

Comment: Do you have auto-layout configured?

Comment: Please edit your edit:"when it is __not__ shown, the initial frame is (0 0; 0 0). When it's __not__, it's always some other value."

Comment: Try: (1) turn off autolayout; (2) move the code to viewWillAppear; (3)giving the imageView a background colour (so you can see it without an image;  (4) init'ing the imageView with no image (so you will know if the issue is related to the image, not the imageView)

Comment: If you definitely need auto-layout, try moving the code to viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your log of the `UIImageView` it show `frame = (0 0; 0 0);` This means that the view will not be shown  since it has a height and width of 0. Which indicates that the image has no size or is `nil`.

The cause of this is most probably because the image your are trying to load is not found:
You should check wether the image is found or not:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
if (!image) {
   NSLog(@"Image could not be found: %@", imageName);
}

imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

Meaning that even if you change the frame you will still see nothing since there is no image loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you set the frame first and set the image next?

```
 imageView = [UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,35,35)];
 [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [rckoenes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/309925/rckoenes) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18694803/766570)  you must always check if the image exists within your bundle path first:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *documentsDirectory 
        = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)
             objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
    if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path])
    {
       UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
       if (!image) {
          NSLog(@"Image could not be found: %@", imageName);
       }

       imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    } else {
       NSLog(@"%@ is not included in the app file bundle!", imageName);
    }
```

that way you'll know if the problem is b/c you don't have the file in the first place.. or b/c there is something wrong with file that prevents iOS from loading it.

Comment: `UIImage imageNamed:` will only work for files in the app bundle not for files in the document directory. Also if `UIImage imageNamed:` return `nil` you can just check the filename to see what is wrong, not need to check whether the file is available on the file syste,